# Issues after changing hosting for Os Commerce Website

Tags: oscommerce

I want to change the site hosting. I have this old site that was on another hosting provider - (http://coachingyou.org/) earlier with HostGator, and I am trying to close my HostGator account and move this site to another hosting but I moved the site and it is not running properly. The inner pages are not working in it. Here is the URL of the website on which I have copied the site: (http://techturners.online/coaching/).
Can anyone suggest with the solution to make the navigations workable?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First of all `chmod 444` to /home3/ruchiwal/public_html/coaching/includes/configure.php for security reasons.

Then I suppose you mean 404 error, and I'm pretty sure the problem is in your `.htaccess` file where you have `RewriteRule` directives. Please check if paths in it match files and folders structure on your new hosting.

**UPD**: I see there's Nginx on your hosting. You will have to use it's rewrite rules instead of Apache's.